# Yii2 модули и компоненты

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Есть к примеру модуль Media(модуль для работы с изображениями). И есть два компонента которые зареганы в нем - Image и Resize.

Image

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\media\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BaseObject;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use app\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\modules\media\helpers\FileHelper;

class Image extends BaseObject
{
    private $files = [];

    public $path;
    public $basePath;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function getData() {}
}
```

Resize

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\media\components;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;
use yii\imagine\Image;
use yii\base\Exception;

class Resize extends BaseObject
{
    private $width;
    private $height;

    public function getAll() {}
}
```

И контроллер в котором хочу это дергать(место правильное я так понимаю для этого или нет ?)

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\media\controllers\backend;

use app\controllers\BackendController;

class ItemController extends BackendController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        var_dump($this->module->Image->getImages()->Resize(['width'=>100, 'height'=>150])->getAll());

        exit();
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать что-то вроде этого и насколько это корректно ? Правильно ли я мыслю ?

```
$this->module->Image->getImages()->Resize->getAll();
```

И если да, как передать свойства в компонент ? Так ругается

```
$this->module->Image->getImages()->Resize(['width'=>100, 'height'=>150])->getAll();
```

Возможно кто-нибудь знает где можно посмотреть пример хорошего модуля(кода) в котором все сделано по уму с DI и прочими плюшками, а не тупо вся логика в контроллере ? Я так понимаю вместо компонентов тут должны быть сервисы, но в Yii их нет(поправьте, если не прав).

Comment: Добрый вечер. Ну для этого надо видеть, как устроен Ваш компонент. А без этого остаётся только гадать...

Comment: Напиши что за модуль ?

Comment: Ну когда я смотрю на Image->getImages()->Resize->getAll(), у меня смутные сомнения возникают. Если ты пишешь свой модуль и спрашиваешь как лучше сделать, то у меня б Image->getImages() возвращал бы массив. И этот массив можно было б закинуть уже в Resize. Resize(Image->getImages(), ['width'=>100, 'height'=>150]). Первый агрумент массив картинок, второй параметры для ресайза

Comment: _для этого надо видеть, как устроен Ваш компонент_ Обновил вопрос. _Напиши что за модуль ?_ - свой велосипед, все как в доках. _Если ты пишешь свой модуль и спрашиваешь как лучше сделать_ Так и есть. _Image->getImages() возвращал бы массив. И этот массив можно было б закинуть уже в Resize_ такой подход показался мне не совсем верным. Все таки объекты и все такое ;)